# Express doesn't want to show images when including an app in another app

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express

[Full source code](https://github.com/LetovoLeTo/leto-main-server)
[Demo](https://letovoleto.onrender.com)

So, I am including an app (leto-timetables) in another app (leto-main-server). When the included app is run by itself, everything works fine and the images are showm. However, when I try to run the app that is including the smaller app, the images just won't work.
Here's the code that's responsible for including the app:

```js
const express = require("express");

// ...
const appTimetables = require("./leto-timetables");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use("/res", express.static("leto-resources"));

// ...
app.use(appTimetables);

app.listen(port);
```

And here's the code from the smaller app:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { join } = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use("/timetables", express.static(join(__dirname, "html")));
app.get("/timetables", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(join(__dirname, "html/index.html"));
});

module.exports = app;
```

The project structure is as follows:

```
leto-timetables
├── html
│   ├── bus_filatov_lug.png
│   ├── bus_tepliy_stan.png
│   ├── canteen.png
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── monday.png
│   ├── saturday.png
│   ├── sunday.png
│   └── tuesday2friday.png
├── index.js
├── LICENSE
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
└── server.js
```

I tried converting the images to PNG because it worked with another app (leto-map), but it didn't work. What's the problem here?